# Unloading data from snowflake into Google Cloud Storage BigTable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to unload data from snowflake into Google Cloud Storage then use a data flow template to upload to BigTable,
I have encountered a problem, I read that if I want to read data from cloud storage Parquet/Avro files to Bigtable I need a specific [schema](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/src/main/resources/schema/avro/bigtable.avsc) from the input Parquet/Avro files.
when I am using the COPY INTO  command to copy the data from the Snowflake database table into one or more files in a Cloud Storage bucket.
I don't have any option to use format type with a specific schema.
how can I solve it? is it necessary?
thanks, Shahar.

links

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-gcs.html
- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-avro-to-bigtable

Comment: Why are you generating files out of Snowflake in Parquet format if it is subsequently causing you issues? Why not create the files as csv?

Answer (score 0):

The Import dataflow template requires data in a specific format as it needs to translate the incoming avro files into Bigtable Mutations.

The source code for the template can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/AvroToBigtable.java). You can adapt the DF pipeline by supplying a custom  `static class AvroToBigtableFn extends DoFn<BigtableRow, KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>>`. It should take CustomAvorRow, instead of a BigtableRow.

Your pipeline will look like:

```
BigtableIO.Write write =
        BigtableIO.write()
            .withProjectId(options.getBigtableProjectId())
            .withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId())
            .withTableId(options.getBigtableTableId());

    pipeline
        .apply("Read from Avro", AvroIO.read(CustomAvroRow.class).from(options.getInputFilePattern()))
        .apply(
            "Transform to Bigtable",
            ParDo.of(
                CustomAvroToBigtableFn.createWithSplitLargeRows(
                    options.getSplitLargeRows(), MAX_MUTATIONS_PER_ROW)))
        .apply("Write to Bigtable", write);
```

You will need to supply a definition of the avro format and write a translation logic similar to the template

```
 static class CustomAvroToBigtableFn extends DoFn<CustomAvroRow, KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>> {

@ProcessElement
    public void processElement(
        @Element CustomAvroRow row, OutputReceiver<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>> out) {
      ImmutableList.Builder<Mutation> mutations = ImmutableList.builder();

// Create Mutations from the CustomAvroRow and add them to mutations


      // Flush any remaining mutations.
      ImmutableList remainingMutations = mutations.build();
      if (!remainingMutations.isEmpty()) {
        out.output(KV.of(key, remainingMutations));
      }
    }
  }
```